# Unintentional lose of a Navigation Bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I have a UITableView which has a navigation bar that can seque to a View Controller of my app via a UINagivationController. The Table View is editable, where I can delete a cell.

I have found what I think is a bug. When I swipe from left to right the tableview goes away to reveal the view Controller. However, if I only half commit to the swipe and only go 3/4 of the way (not fully going to the View Controller) and return back to the Table View, the navigation bar is removed. I have programmatically removed the navigation bar of the view controller, but I have not removed it from Table View Controller. It is incredibly important for my table view to have the navigation bar, as it is the only way that I can return to the view controller (once the navigation bar is gone,  it no longer allows for me to segue back to the View Controller by using the left to right swipe for some reason).

Has anyone seen this problem? Is there code that I need to add to ensure that the Navigation bar does not disappear?

Comment: Where are you programatically removing the nav bar? Maybe you can move it to another part of the VC lifecycle to ensure it isn't removed by an aborted swipe. (Post this code if you can.)

Comment: I've added the programatic removal of the nav bar at the viewdidload of the viewController. However, I wonder, is there a way to ensure that the navigation bar reloads at the viewdidappear of the TableView?

Comment: Additionally, is there a way that I can remove the swipe gesture of the segue to go to the View Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by removing the ability of the pop gesture recogniser using this code in the viewDidLoad( ): self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.enabled = false

Comment: unfortunately, it did not work for me.