# Swipe back causes navigation bar hides immediately (not smoothly) when the first view controller hides its navigation bar in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swipe-gesture

I have view controller which navigation bar is hidden.

```
navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

I push another controller when tap on a button.

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(qrGenerateVC, animated: true)
```

In the second view controller the navigation bar is not hidden.
In other situations when I swipe back the second navigation bar hides smoothly but in this situation It disappear when I start swiping back. so it makes the view look not good.

---

This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462543/large-navigation-bar-background-gets-clear-color-when-swiping-back-to-root-viewc) which does not have answer. And the view is similar too.
Before swipe [screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvWOf.jpg) 
After swipe [screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3vg1.jpg)  
These images are from that question. but similar thing happens here.

Comment: In Which method you set isNavigationBarHidden and Show?

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani Thanks. Nav bar is hidden in view will appear in the first viewController.

Comment: Does your second view controller has a separate UINavigationController? I mean your how did you connect first viewcontroller to the second one? segue way to second viewcontroller or to a navigation controller?

Comment: @Vahid Not it doesn't have. I push the second view controller with this code: self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController)

Comment: This one fixed my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597090/unintentional-lose-of-a-navigation-bar?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Set this in your second view controller

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(_ hidden: Bool, animated: Bool)` in your viewController's `override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)`.

The key thing is that you should use the `animated` variable from the method's parameters and pass it to the `setNavigationBarHidden` method.